# How do you change your external ip?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What im trying to do is bypass ip detection from websites that i crawl.

Each website limit the amount of times per day you can crawl the site.

They limit your actions by reading your ip.

I use virtual machine (gcloud) to do my crawling so i won't keep my personal pc running.

When this happens, the website puts a block because of my ip.

Im trying to bypass this detection by getting a new ip.

My vm everytime i stop and restart the instance gives me the same 2 external ip addresses.

And in gcloud i thought since the setting was not static and set to ethereal, they would give you a new ip each time you stop the instance, but no.

They only flip flop between the same 2 external ip addresses.

I've learned that in my vm, the external ip is the ip websites look at to see if this address has been here before.

If i can continuously get a new address (like every time i stop the vm) i can keep crawling the websites.

BUT, the vm only gives me the same 2 external ip addresses... I've read that there is a shell command where you can demand a new ip but i do not know how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain different public IP addresses so that you can bypass IP detection? Your question is not worded very well so I do not understand what you are asking. I would delete this question and create a new question with better details.

Comment: John if i could do that i would but i can not until 3 more days, so i will edit this question and add more detail and yes im trying to obtain a different ip address each time i reset the instance. Currently when i reset the vm the external ip gives the same 2 external ip adressess. for example 20:299:23:23 and 23.299:21:24, everytime i STOP the instance to get a new ip,  the external ip (which websites use to check your ip) flip flops between those 2 external ips (20:299:23:23 and 20.299:21:24) So what im trying to do is get a new ip anyway possible through console command, or reset

Comment: You do not have control over ephemeral addresses. You could allocate static IP addresses and then change which one is assigned to your instance. You could clone your instance to different regions and launch from there.

Comment: awesome, so cloning and launching the instance from different regions will automatically allocate the static ip? or do i have to do this manually because there is an option to reserve a static ip and im not sure if this allocates the ip

Comment: astounding john, this really works

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to assign a static IP to your VM and [change](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign) it when you need to do it for your use case. You can change or assign an external IP address, either ephemeral or static, to an existing instance by modifying the instance's access configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can reboot your modem and this way you should be assigned a new public ip

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).